# retrieve data from db to form on click (MVC entity framework)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, bootstrap-modal

I want to retrieve the selected data from db to a form for "update" operation in mvc. I want to do it with modal.

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question and show what you have tried. There are lots of tutorials out there to get started. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is far too broad, please read the [help]

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for: https://cmatskas.com/update-an-mvc-partial-view-with-ajax/

**Update:** As someone pointed out, i shouldn't just redirect you to an article without giving a "real" answer. So:

You can create an action that returns a partial view containing the updated values and get that partial view using AJAX. You can get a detailed, and propably better, explanation in the link above.

**Update 2:** For example (not tested):

Your Action:

```
public ViewResult GetForm()
{
    //Get some data from your database
    var model = new FormBindingModel
    {
        //Populate this model with data from your database
    };

    return View("_Form", model);
}
```

In your (parent) page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#something").on("event", function () {
            $("#formcontainer").empty().append('@(Url.Action("GetForm","ControllerName")));
        });     
    });
</script>
```

With this example your ajax call retrieves a partial page (your form) populated by an object, but i guess you can make your own implementation to fit your needs.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: I applaud the effort you've put in here but you have made a number of assumptions on what the OP wants, etc. Generally I'd try and avoid answering poor questions like this. You'll find quickly it's a thankless task